# Why does my code result in a compile error?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

The code in question is as follows:

```
importjava.util.ArrayList;
importjava.util.Collections;
importjava.util.List;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Human> humans= newArrayList<Human>();
        humans.add(newHuman(13));
        humans.add(newHuman(33));
        humans.add(newHuman(21));
        humans.add(newHuman(21));
        Collections.sort(humans); 
        System.out.print(humans.get(0).age);
        System.out.print(humans.size()); 
    }
}
class Human implements Comparable<Human> {
    int age;
    public Human(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public int compareTo(Human h) {
        return h.age.compareTo(this.age);
    }
}
```

I was wondering why this code causes a compilation error? I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Some extra details:

Comment: Typo : `importjava...` should be `import java...`. Same problem here : `newArrayList`

Comment: Why are you surprised by the compiler error? You write `newArrayList` or `newHuman` ... where have you learned that you don't need a whitespace between `new` and the type name?

Comment: also: int doesn't implement any interfaces, you can't call compareTo on it.

Answer (score 1):

Primitive type like shrot, int, long, double do not implement Comparable interface. make your instance variable Object type. also changes in imports, while creating new object ( new Human(13)).

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.List;

    public class Test{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<Human> humans= new ArrayList<Human>();
            humans.add(new Human(13));
            humans.add(new Human(33));
            humans.add(new Human(21));
            humans.add(new Human(21));
            Collections.sort(humans); 
            System.out.print(humans.get(0).age);
            System.out.print(humans.size()); 
        }
    }
    class Human implements Comparable<Human> {
        Integer age;
        public Human(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }
        public int compareTo(Human h) {
            return h.age.compareTo(this.age);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you miss many spaces in code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Human> humans= new ArrayList<Human>();
        humans.add(new Human(13));
        humans.add(new Human(33));
        humans.add(new Human(21));
        humans.add(new Human(21));
        Collections.sort(humans); 
        System.out.print(humans.get(0).age);
        System.out.print(humans.size()); 
    }
}
class Human implements Comparable<Human> {
    int age;
    public Human(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public int compareTo(Human h) {
        return h.age - this.age;
    }
}
```